# Server not reachable within a VPN (SNX) out of a Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, vpn, checkpoint

I am working with the latest Manjaro with the kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.10.15-1-MANJARO.

I am connected to my company network via VPN.
For this I use SNX with the build version 800010003.

When I start a Docker container (Docker version 20.10.3, build 48d30b5b32) which should connect to a machine from the company network, I get the following message.

```
[maurice@laptop ~]$ docker run --rm alpine ping company-server
ping: bad address 'company-server'
```

Also using the IP from the 'company-server' doesn't work.

A ping outside the container works, no matter using the name or IP.

The resolv.conf looks correct to me.

```
[maurice@laptop ~]$ docker run --rm alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search lan
nameserver 10.1.0.250
nameserver 10.1.0.253
nameserver 192.168.86.1
```

What I have found out so far.

If I downgrade packages glibc and lib32-glibc to version 2.32-5, the ping out of the container works again. Because of dependencies I have also to downgrade gcc, gcc-libs and lib32-gcc-libs to version 10.2.0-4.

I tried the whole thing with a fresh Pop OS 20.10 installation, same problem.
I also did a test with another VPN (OpenVPN) which worked fine. However, this was only a test scenario and cannot be used as an alternative.

I have been looking for a solution for several days but have not found anything. It would be really nice if someone could help me with this.

Comment: I'm use arch with the same issue you discribe
OS: Manjaro 20.2.1 Nibia
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.10.15-1-MANJARO

Comment: I have the same problem as described. I also added a comment on the aur.archlinux.org snx package site, but did not get any answer to this yet. The problem seems to appear also on other Linux distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR:
on kernel >5.8 the tunsnx interface is no longer created with global scope and need to be recreated. small script to the rescure https://gist.github.com/Fahl-Design/ec1e066ec2ef8160d101dff96a9b56e8

Longer version:

Here are my findings and the solution to (temp) fix it:

Steps to reproduce:

- connect your snx tunnel
- see ping fails to server behind tunnel

  ```
  docker run --rm -ti --net=company_net busybox /bin/sh -c "ping 192.168.210.210"
  ```
- run this command to check ip and scope of the "tunsnx" interface

  ```
  ip -o address show "tunsnx" | awk -F ' +' '{print $4 " " $6 " " $8}'
  ```

if you get something like

```
192.168.210.XXX 192.168.210.30/32 247
```

or (Thx Timz)

```
192.168.210.XXX 192.168.210.30/32 nowhere
```

the scope is **not** set to "global" and no connection can be established

to fix this, like "ronan lanore" suggested, you need to change the scope to global

this can be done with a little helper script like this one:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Usage: [dry_run=1] [debug=1] [interface=tunsnx] docker-fix-snx
#
# Credits to: https://github.com/docker/for-linwux/issues/288#issuecomment-825580160
#
# Env Variables:
#   interface - Defaults to tunsnx
#   dry_run - Set to 1 to have a dry run, just printing out the iptables command
#   debug   - Set to 1 to see bash substitutions

set -eu

_log_stderr() {
  echo "$*" >&2
}

if [ "${debug:=0}" = 1 ]; then
  set -x
  dry_run=${dry_run:=1}
fi

: ${dry_run:=0}
: ${interface:=tunsnx}

data=($(ip -o address show "$interface" | awk -F ' +' '{print $4 " " $6 " " $8}'))

LOCAL_ADDRESS_INDEX=0
PEER_ADDRESS_INDEX=1
SCOPE_INDEX=2

if [ "$dry_run" = 1 ]; then
  echo "[-] DRY-RUN MODE"
fi

if [ "${data[$SCOPE_INDEX]}" == "global" ]; then
  echo "[+] Interface ${interface} is already set to global scope. Skip!"
  exit 0
else
  echo "[+] Interface ${interface} is set to scope ${data[$SCOPE_INDEX]}."

  tmpfile=$(mktemp --suffix=snxwrapper-routes)
  echo "[+] Saving current IP routing table..."
  if [ "$dry_run" = 0 ]; then
    sudo ip route save >$tmpfile
  fi

  echo "[+] Deleting current interface ${interface}..."
  if [ "$dry_run" = 0 ]; then
    sudo ip address del ${data[$LOCAL_ADDRESS_INDEX]} peer ${data[$PEER_ADDRESS_INDEX]} dev ${interface}
  fi

  echo "[+] Recreating interface ${interface} with global scope..."
  if [ "$dry_run" = 0 ]; then
    sudo ip address add ${data[$LOCAL_ADDRESS_INDEX]} dev ${interface} peer ${data[$PEER_ADDRESS_INDEX]} scope global
  fi

  echo "[+] Restoring routing table..."
  if [ "$dry_run" = 0 ]; then
    sudo ip route restore <$tmpfile 2>/dev/null
  fi

  echo "[+] Cleaning temporary files..."
  rm $tmpfile

  echo "[+] Interface ${interface} is set to global scope. Done!"
  if [ "$dry_run" = 0 ]; then
    echo "[+] Result:"
    ip -o address show "tunsnx" | awk -F ' +' '{print $4 " " $6 " " $8}'
  fi
  exit 0
fi

[ "$debug" = 1 ] && set +x
```

Comment: In my case I get the scope "nowhere" when executing the 'ip -o address show ...' command. But I tested your script and it works fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me now. Nothing big change but tunsnx interface scope change from global to 247. Delete it and re create with global scope.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more how you solve this problem, respectively how you delete and re-create the interface manually? In my understanding SNX creates the interface automatically and removes it when disconnecting.

Comment: I use a netwrok-manager script into disptached.d
`ip address del ${snxInfo[$LOCAL_ADDRESS_INDEX]} peer ${snxInfo[$PEER_ADDRESS_INDEX]} dev ${iface}
  ip address add ${snxInfo[$LOCAL_ADDRESS_INDEX]} dev ${iface} peer ${snxInfo[$PEER_ADDRESS_INDEX]} scope global`

Answer (score 1):

Just for collection of possible solutions. I had the same problem but found that "tunsnx" interface was configured properly with "global" keyword. In my case the problem was that `snx` was started after docker daemon and restarting docker `service docker restart` helped.